# pChart DisplayValues for only one series

Tags: php, pchart

I am using the latest pChart and I am trying to only have one series display its points labels on a line chart. Below you can see the chart and it has 3 series with data point labels on all series. I would like to just have the heavy green series only have the point labels.

[Chart Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5yv5.png)

```
 /* Draw the line chart */ 
 $myPicture->drawLineChart();
 $myPicture->drawPlotChart(array("DisplayValues"=>TRUE,"PlotBorder"=>TRUE,"BorderSize"=>2,"Surrounding"=>-60,"BorderAlpha"=>80));
```

Comment: I might say something stupid, But its just an idea
Is there a way you could overlaps charts and have one char with one serie with display values and the other chart with the other serie with no display values ?

Comment: you might be able to do this, but I am rendering them as images so overlaying a image on top of another would not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`writeLabel`](http://wiki.pchart.net/doc.draw.writeLabel.html) method, it puts a bubble over the selected values, but it can be customized in the third parameter.

The first parameter should be the name of the green label, and the second parameter should be an array which contains all the keys of the points.